# Orbital speed change when closer to the sun

Tags: orbital-motion, speed

So a thought had passed my mind recently and i was wondering if an object like mercury has a greater orbital speed than the earth. Yes, i am aware that distance makes a difference but i talking about the speed in general. For example the planets in the picture are all aligned and all start off at the same speed.[image: The planets aligned]

Comment: Do a search on Kepler's Laws.

Comment: Ok i did a through search but just to verify id does remain constant, correct?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Planets that orbit close to the sun travel faster than those that are more distant, and also when a given planet's orbit is at its closest to the sun that is when it's moving fastest. I won't write a full answer because you need to do some more basic research on this topic yourself first.